# How to intersect a raster subset with a buffered vector layer (points) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am a bit new in the GIS and QGIS sphere so maybe my question will look a bit naive, but at the same time it means it should probably be easy for most of you guys ;-)

I work in QGIS. I have 2 layers:

(1) raster: grid representing global land cover / CRS "WGS 84"

(2) vector: a series of point representing factories / CRS "WGS 84"

I would like to select a subset from the grid only pixels with value 11 & 14 and intersect these selected pixels with a buffer of 50km around each factory. The result I would like to save as a new layer (preferably raster).

How can I do that in a simple but correct way?